# acquireToken callback never called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, adal, adal.js

I've made some progress after my [initial post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727863/adal-js-not-setting-props-in-localstorage) on integrating adal.js with Vue.js. I'm successfully logging in, and the properties I'd expect to be set are being set in localStorage.

However, calls to `acquireToken` never call the the callback I'm passing. The code looks like this:

```
let url = 'https://api.webserver.com/api/endpoint';

authContext.acquireToken(url, (err, token) => {
  console.log(`acquiring token for ${url}`);
  console.log(err, token);
});
```

Looking at the source for adal.js, the method signature for `acquireToken` is as follows:

```
AuthenticationContext.prototype.acquireToken(resource, callback)
```

The callback isn't called. Is the `url` value I'm passing what the method is expecting? I'm unclear about this.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your init post, you have completed the Azure AD application's configuration, you can try to replace the `url` to the `client_id`, under `acquireToken()` function.

According to the source code of `adal for js`, the `acquireToken()` calls `getCachedToken()` at [`L515`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L515).

And the function [`getCachedToken()`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L315) will get the token in browser's session via `var token = this._getItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + resource);` You can check all the AD info in DEV TOOL of browser after you successfully login. We can find that the resource here is in the client_id format.

[image]

Comment: Alright, I got this working! But... the token doesn't appear to refreshing properly. I was under the assumption that successive calls to acquireToken would keep the token updated. However, the session seems to end after about 30 minutes, and callback isn't called in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In AdalJS version 1.0.13, If you want to have a callback, you can use the following code:

```
                authContext.acquireToken('https://api.webserver.com/api/endpoint').then(function (token) {
                    console.log(token)
                },function(error){
                    console.log('Failed to acquire token');  
                }
            );
```

Comment: Are you sure? acquireToken doesn't return a Promise or any type of then-able object.

Comment: What version of adal.js?

Comment: I am using AdalJS v1.0.13

Comment: Gotcha. This is no longer the case as of 1.0.14, the current version (though I wish it were!!!). I'd be happy to remove the downvote if you update your answer to specify you're that the promise approach you're using works in 1.0.13.